# Evaluate $\int e^{2\cos x}\cos 2x dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

I tried substituting various formulas (half-angle) for reducing above equation to form $e^{f'(x)}  f(x)$. Also tried to substitute $\cos x /\cos 2x$ to solve by using integration by parts but failed.

We get $$\int e^{2\cos x}\cos 2x dx$$ while reducing Bernoulli's differential equation. The original problem statement was,

$$\frac{dy}{dx} + y \sin x = y^3 \, \cos 2x$$

Comment: I suppose that the expression in title is not correct.

Comment: Please check the edit. People are interpreting the title in different ways.

Comment: Rechek your integrating factor. I have posted my workings.

Comment: That antiderivative can't be written in "closed form".  You just have to write the solution of the differential equation in terms of the antiderivative.